# Error paginate does not exist with Vue.js and Laravel in controller

Tags: laravel, vue.js

```
public function all_contact(){
  $contacts = contacts::with('user')->orderBy('id','desc')->get()->paginate(5);
  return response()->json([
    'contacts'=>$contacts
  ],200);
}
```

It gives error:

```
Method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection::paginate does not exist.
```

Comment: Remove the ->get()

Answer (score 2):

You are using `->get()->paginate(5);`.When using `->get()` method you get `Collection` instance. Change your code to

```
public function all_contact(){
    $contacts = contacts::with('user')->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(5);
    return response()->json([
        'contacts'=>$contacts
    ],200);
 }
```